# How to render different templates per user status

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to render a different template per user is_teacher status.

here is my model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

here is my view.py

```
def home(request):
    if User.profile.is_teacher==True:
        return render(request, 'home/home.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'home/tutor_home.html')
```

I am having issues with the second line, I want a situation where if is_teacher is true in user profile then it renders a template and if false it renders another template

Comment: `if request.user.profile.is_teacher:`.

Comment: Thank you, post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the logged in user with `request.user`, so that means that we can work with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    template = 'home/home.html' if request.user.profile.is_teacher else 'home/tutor_home.html'
    return render(request, template)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).